# Poincaré with spontaneously broken translations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, poincare-symmetry

What is the physical interpretation of Poincaré symmetries with spontaneously broken spatial and temporal translations?

Is there an interesting low-energy effective model for it and what are its physical properties?

Comment: Spontaneously broken spatial translations are what characterize crystals to some extent, the associated Nambu-Goldstone bosons being phonons. I believe the associated object but for SSB of time translation invariance would be a [time crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_crystal#Time_translation_symmetry), but I don't know much about it.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan Is there a simple way to understand why the rotations are not also broken for the case of a crystal (this would have been my naive expectation)?

Comment: Required reading: [Low & Manohar, 2002](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.88.101602) .